# Difference of two Quaternion

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, quaternions

I want to calculate the difference of one List of four quaternions(sample quaternions) to a set of 4x5 quaterions(reference quaternions), please find below the given lists as an example:

```
sampleQuaternion:
[ 6.8028995e-01  8.6924500e-02 -2.7695930e-01  6.7354980e-01,  9.2199555e-01  6.6694000e-02 -1.5594620e-01  3.4811020e-01,  8.6818795e-01  2.8909950e-01 -1.9546280e-01  3.5309480e-01,  9.9454195e-01  9.5241500e-02 -5.6380000e-04  4.3782300e-02,  1.4513655e-01  6.7568850e-01 -7.0157520e-01  1.7325420e-01 ]

referenceQuaternion:
[array([ 0.67958385,  0.08526331, -0.27927537,  0.673577  ]), array([ 0.91941354,  0.06026183, -0.16610318,  0.35022307]), array([ 0.83122792,  0.30900904, -0.21607731,  0.3508847 ]), array([9.94764654e-01, 9.48417100e-02, 2.22094000e-04, 4.52554440e-02]), array([ 0.1694425 ,  0.65179323, -0.68420773,  0.1678294 ])]
```

I cut the reference quaternions list down to the one very relevant row for clarity sakes. But of course I can also provide the whole list.

What gives me headaches is the resulting distanceList:

```
[1.0007654084282076, 0.9996114310614366, 0.9779760691471999, 1.0003507749395835, 0.9745277103139326]
```

All quaternions are apparently unit quaternions. It should be a closer distance, shouldn't it?

Below are the functions:

```
import quaternionnic as qu

def calculateSampleMidDistance(self, cloudMids=None, sampleList=None):
    """ first input value is required to be the list of cloudMids and second the sampleList received by the glove
    both can either be an array or a list"""
    cloudMids = np.asarray(cloudMids)
    sampleList = np.asarray(self.bundleForFinger(sampleList))
    gestureDistance = []
    for gesture in range(len(cloudMids)):
        fingerDistance = []
        for finger in range(5):
            refQuaternion = cloudMids[gesture][finger]
            sampleQuaternion = sampleList[finger]
            fingerDistance.append(self.calculateDistance(q1=refQuaternion, q2=sampleQuaternion))
        gestureDistance.append(fingerDistance)
    return gestureDistance
```

and

```
def calculateDistance(self, q1=None, q2=None):
    """calculating the distance of two quaterions wherein the first input quaterion is the reference quaternion and
    the second is to where the distance shall be calculated"""
    # assertion that quaternions are arrays
    q1 = np.asarray(q1)
    q2 = np.asarray(q2)
    # initialise local variables
    q1_conj = np.zeros(4)
    difference = np.zeros(4)
    distance = np.zeros(1)

    qu.algebra.conjugate(q1, q1_conj)
    qu.algebra.multiply(q1_conj, q2, difference)
    qu.algebra.absolute(difference, distance)
    return distance[0]
```

the `self.bundleForFinger(sampleList)` just takes the recorded sample list which just provides all basis vectors and is sorting them for the quaternions.

thanks in advance